# Javascript Promise chaining

Tags: javascript, promises

I recently started working with JS `Promise`s. What I always like to do, is create function, which returns a `Promise` with the final desired result, but I only do 1 operation/`then`. Consider something like this (this fetches the versions of an npm package in an array in reverse order):

```
function packageVersions(name) {
  return fetchJson(npmUrls.getPackageUrl(name))
    .then(npmPackage => npmPackage.versions)
    .then(versionsObject => Object.keys(versionsObject))
    .then(versions => versions.sort((a, b) => b.localeCompare(a)));
}
```

Like if I was doing a lots of .maps sequentially.

**My question would be:** is this considered a good practice in general? Could this have significant perfomance drawbacks, if I do a lots of chaining? Do you consider this unreadable in any way?

Would this be better?

```
function packageVersions(name) {
  return fetchJson(npmUrls.getPackageUrl(name))
    .then(npmPackage => {
        const versions = Object.keys(npmPackage.versions);
        return versions.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b));
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It potentially could have some performance issues but that probably isn't a big deal.  It would be adding an asynchronous "tick" after each `then` when in this case it doesn't need to.

The big issue to me is that I would assume at first glance that the promise chain calls asynchronous methods even though it doesn't.